# Closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k} h^{(n-k)}(0)f^{(k-1)}(0)$

Tags: derivatives, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, closed-form

Is there a closed form for:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k} h^{(n-k)}(0)f^{(k-1)}(0)$$

where: $$h(x)=(1-x)^{\alpha}(A-Bx)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha}$$ and $$f(x)=-x(1-x)^{-1-\alpha}(A-Bx)^{-(\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha)-1}$$ where $h^{(n-k)}(0)$ is the $(n-k)$th derivative of $h(x)$ at $x=0$.

I came across this trying to find the generating function for a distribution. I first solved a first order differential equation [by integrating factor](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html). As a result I obtained:

$$y(x)=(1-x)^{\alpha}(A-Bx)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha} \int -x(1-x)^{-1-\alpha}(A-Bx)^{-(\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha)-1}dx$$
 Next I need to find the **Taylor series** of $y(x)=\sum \frac{y^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$. This requires the evaluation of the sum in this question.

There seems to be a relation between $h$ and $f$ that makes me think(hope) there should be a nice closed form solution for it.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: 1) 'Derivativation' isn't a word, so you should try to revise that title. 2) Can you elaborate on the origin of your summation arose? It looks like this is arising from applying the Leibniz rule in order to evaluate a higher derivative of the product $f(x) h(x)$ at $x=0$, and I'd rather not 'undo' work you've already done.

Comment: 1) Title is revised. 2)I obtained $y(x)=(1-x)^{\alpha}(A-Bx)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha}\int-x(1-x)^{-1-\alpha}(A-Bx)^{-(\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha)-1} dx$ by solving a differential equation. What I'm interested in, is to find the Taylor series of $y(x)$ and therefore I need to $\sum \frac{y^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ which in turn requires the evaluation of the sum, I asked in this post.

Comment: Could you place that into the question itself? It's helpful context. (Also, is that $\int$ symbol positioned correctly?

Comment: Just did so, I added the whole background, except for the differential equation. And yes integral is in the right position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivative of $h(x)$ seems to go something like

$$h^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^n(\alpha)_n A^{\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha}+(-B)^n\left({\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha}\right)_n A^{\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha-n}$$

And for $f(x)$ we have

$$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^n A^{-(\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha)-1}$$

So the sum will be

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left((-1)^{n-k}(\alpha)_{n-k} A^{\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha}+(-B)^{n-k}\left({\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha}\right)_{n-k} A^{\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha-n+k}\right)\left((-1)^{k-1} A^{-(\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha)-1}\right)\\
=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{A}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(\alpha)_{n-k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left({\frac{1}{\gamma}-\alpha}\right)_{n-k}\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)^{n-k}\right)$$

Exist a Sheffer sequence that relates binomial coefficient with a complementary pair of falling factorial but just for one falling factorial I dont found nothing. If you can relates binomial and a falling factorial in a closed form then maybe a closed form for the expression.

Maybe trying some finite differentiation.

**UPDATE**: well, wolfram-alpha says that [exists a relation](http://goo.gl/VCnI5e) but Im not sure if this is a form more "closed" or not.

And for the second addend [exists another relation](http://goo.gl/aFh9kK).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid working with Hypergeometric Functions. But it seems inevitable. Since my final goal is to find the behavior of this distribution, whether it has a power law or an exponential form, and I can't find a final conclusion using Hypergeometric functions with parameters.

Comment: @yasamin you can try to type the entire equation on some CAS and see what happen as last chance :p

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to solve it using **Mathemathica** now however it is not clear to me how I can find the behavior of a function. I will accept your solution to close this question.